# The name does not exist in the current context even that Inherits match the filename

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a common issue altough following all the answers in SO that I read, I can't still solve it.
I have this simple aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GestaoFicheiros.aspx.cs" Inherits="fileManager.GestaoFicheiros" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
...
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

And the code behind:

```
namespace fileManager
{
    public partial class GestaoFicheiros : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {

                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, in code Behind, I am getting the Error of the question, in all the fields that I am trying to acess from the `.aspx` file, namely StatusLabel and FileUploadControl.

What should be the issue here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve it. I had to click on the `aspx` file and, in the Project menu (VS2017), I needed to convert to a web application.